# How to change the window title font color in the adwaita theme?

Tags: linux-mint, colors, theme

I use cinnamon mint 17.1, and I found that the window title font color is difficult to distinguish from the background. I know that the theme can be changed from the control option under theme but I like this one and would like to know how to tweak it. I found the files under `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita` and simply changed wherever I saw color but nothing seemed to change so posting it here.
The gtk3.0 has few files like gtk.css and gtk-dark.css but they just contain these two lines respectively.
`@import url("resource:///org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-main-dark.css");`
`@import url("resource:///org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-main-dark.css");`
So how to go about modifying them? Thank you.

Comment: That's because the theme is a binary file - you'll have to hack it and maintain your own, customized version, [see my post here and the guide I linked to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175399)

Comment: That works for cinnamon?

Comment: No idea, I don't use cinnamon...It should work, it's a gnome fork after all...

Answer (score 2):

`~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
/* REMOVE "-dark" IF USING LIGHT THEME */
@import url("resource:///org/gtk/libgtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained-dark.css");

/* THIS ONE CHANGES TITLEBAR COLOR */
headerbar.titlebar,
headerbar.titlebar:active {
    background:#3F51B5;
}

/* THIS CHANGES NAUTILUS SEARCH BAR */
.horizontal.path-bar-box,
row:selected:backdrop {
     background:#3F51B5;
     border-color:#3F51B5;
}
```

To debug and find fitting CSS Selectors, open a GTK3 app with environment variable GTK_DEBUG=interactive. For example,

```
GTK_DEBUG=interactive nautilus
```

This should open a inspector for the GTK window. If it's not there, press Ctrl+Shift+I.

[image: screenshot of inspector]